# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable in Python "for recursive equations in a double for loop, probably index-related problem"

Tags: python, recursion, indexing

I am trying to represent a real-life barn (closed queuing network) problem with some AMVA (Approximate Mean Value Analysis). I have 6 recursive equations to be computed. I am getting this **TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable** for the **last line of my code**. I think it might be index-related, but I am not sure of course. I would appreciate any idea that could help me.

```
import math

H = 10 #number of cows
c = [0,1,1,12,3,27,H] #capacity of the stations
v = [0,0.164,0.155,0.235,0.17,0.276,1] #relative visit frequencies to the stations
s = [0,8.41,6.38,15.0,3.18,38.9,5.36] #mean service times
sigma = [0,2.52,6.25,11.9,2.3,60.3,0] #st. dev. of service times

R = [0] #residual service times

for i in range(1,7):
    r = (s[i]/2)*(1+((sigma[i]/s[i])**2))
    R.append(r)


W = [[0 for x in range (7)] for y in range (H+1)] #mean waiting time at station i
S = [[0 for x in range (7)] for y in range (H+1)] #mean visit time at station i (waiting + service time)
ARRIVAL = [[0 for x in range (7)] for y in range (H+1)] #mean number of visits per time unit to station i
L = [[0 for x in range (7)] for y in range (H+1)] #mean number of cows waiting at station i
UTIL = [[0 for x in range (7)] for y in range (H+1)] #server utilization at station i
Q = [[0 for x in range (7)] for y in range (H+1)] #probability that all servers are busy at station i


for h in range(1,H+1): #Recursive equations (to find variables when h = 2, we need variables when h = 1 for example)
    for i in range(1,7):
        W[h][i] = Q[h-1][i]*R[i]/c[i] + L[h-1][i]*s[i]/c[i]
        S[h][i] = W[h][i] + s[i]
        ARRIVAL[h][i] = (v[i]*h) / (sum(v[i]*S[h][i] for i in range(1,7)))
        L[h][i] = ARRIVAL[h][i] * W[h][i]
        UTIL = (ARRIVAL[h][i]*s[i])/c[i]
        if h < c[i]:
            Q[h][i] = 0
        else:
            Q[h][i] = (((c[i]*UTIL[h][i])**c[i])/math.factorial(c[i]))*((1-UTIL[h][i])*sum(((c[i]*UTIL[h][i])**k)/math.factorial(k) for k in range(c[i]-1))+(((c[i]*UTIL[h][i])**c[i])/math.factorial(c[i])))**-1
```

Comment: `UTIL = (ARRIVAL[h][i]*s[i])/c[i]`, seems to be a single number to me. Then you have multiple `UTIL[h][i]`-s raising the error. Based on the initialization near to the beginning, you wanted `UTIL[h][i] = (ARRIVAL[h][i]*s[i])/c[i]`

Comment: Did you get the chance to see how long "the last line of my code" is? Please try to reduce that (along with the rest of your code) into something more readable which reproduces the problem. Heck, you might even spot the problem yourself (which is rather hard considering the current state of your code) during the process. Why don't you start with writing it as a proper `for` loop? Those shortcuts can be helpful in reducing code-size and making it look cleaner and neater, but they're not designated for you to write an entire program in a single line of code.

Comment: @tevemadar Thanks! That was the little detail I couldn't see. I forgot to add indexes to "UTIL".

Comment: @goodvibration I understand your concern. But that is just a super complex mathematical equation that I think couldn't be further reduced to anything. But the problem is solved. Thanks for your suggestions anyway!

Comment: You couldn't place the `for` part in a separate line??? I sincerely doubt that!!!

Comment: @goodvibration I am not a programming or python expert, I am an Industrial Engineering student. I am used to writing `for` loop right after the summation. But I guess you say that should work too: `for k in range(c[i]-1):` `sum(...whatever...)`